# SEO | VueJS | Why do I see "We're sorry but desk-app doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue." in web browser?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, javascript

I set up a single page application using Vue.js and Firebase.

It works fine but when I search for the website in Google Chrome, this is what pops up :

[image]

I expect to see a proper description, instead of "We're sorry but ... Please enable it to continue."

Here's the code of the file index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>desk.community</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems that Google Search crawlers catch the noscript tag content, rather than the rendered components.

[image]

So far, I used Google Search Console to request re-index of my page, but nothing changed.

Comment: A [meta description tag](https://moz.com/learn/seo/meta-description) might really help out in this situation.

Comment: Thank you @Maximilian Laumeister. I added a meta description tag. I'm not sure whether it will solve the issue that Googlebot doesn't seem to see the rendered pages of my single page application. I added above a screenshot from Google Search Console showing that Googlebot's screenshot is a blank page ...